# New Calculated Table to Split Duration Hourly

Tags: powerbi, dax

i've got a datasheet with a bunch of tasks, their start/end time, duration and start day.

| Task | Start Time | End Time | Duration | Start Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | 21:00 | 22:15 | 1:15 | Monday |
| Task1 | 21:20 | 23:30 | 2:10 | Monday |
| Task2 | 23:00 | 23:20 | 0:20 | Tuesday |

What I'm trying to do is put this data into a new calculated table that would split each task and plot a new row for the mins spent in each hour, as determined by the duration. For example:

| Task | Hour | Mins in Hour | Start Day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Task1 | 21 | 60 | Monday |
| Task1 | 22 | 15 | Monday |
| Task1 | 21 | 40 | Monday |
| Task1 | 22 | 60 | Monday |
| Task1 | 23 | 30 | Monday |
| Task2 | 23 | 20 | Tuesday |

I'm having no luck, could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with PQ

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Task " = _t, #"Start Time " = _t, #"End Time " = _t, #"Duration " = _t, #"Start Day" = _t]),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Index",{{"Task ", type text}, {"Start Time ", type time}, {"End Time ", type time}, {"Duration ", type time}, {"Start Day", type text}}),
    #"Inserted Time Subtraction" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Subtraction", each [#"End Time "] - [#"Start Time "], type duration),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Time Subtraction", "Custom", each let x = Duration.TotalMinutes([Subtraction]),
    y = if x<0 then x*-1 else x in y),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom.1", each List.Times([#"Start Time "],[Custom],#duration(0,0,1,0))),
    #"Expanded Custom.1" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom.1"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom.1",{{"Custom.1", type time}}),
    #"Inserted Hour" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Hour", each Time.Hour([Custom.1]), Int64.Type),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Inserted Hour", {"Index", "Hour"}, {{"min", each List.Min([Custom.1]), type nullable time}, {"max", each List.Max([Custom.1]), type nullable time}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Duration.TotalMinutes([max] - [min])+1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, #"Added Custom2", {"Index"}, "Added Custom2", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom2", {"Hour", "Custom"}, {"Hour", "Custom"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Expanded Added Custom2",{"Task ", "Hour", "Custom", "Start Day"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"Custom", "MinsInHours"}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"MinsInHours", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

[image: Solution]

**`Edit`**

The same code will work with whatever row gets added

From here
[image: Solution]

To
[image: OneMore]

Comment: Unless i'm using this wrong, it doesn't seem to be very flexible. Works for this data sheet, but adding in more tasks just presents me with static info.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is fully dynamic cause I built it that way. Provide the dataset where it does not work for me to test out. I have put a screenshot with an additional row to show you that it should work.

Comment: Ah I see, so I've edited the source and added in extra rows but I'm getting an error. Expression.Error: The 'increment' argument is out of range: Details: 0.00:01:00

here is my data sheet  https://file.io/pYK9hMUnDpNs

Comment: Edited the code. please give this a try

Comment: That now works! My last question would be: because this is only a portion of my dataset which is already contained in a separate table formatted exactly like the attached. Is it possible to amend the source so that the data is being pulled from another table named (task_hours). Or if thats not possible, the source could be a static excel sheet like the attached?

Comment: Got it working! Thank you very much